# public endpoint for load-balancer service not found

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I have an issue to list loadbalancers on open stack using cli

```
from@ge ~
$ openstack loadbalancer list
public endpoint for load-balancer service not found

from@ge ~
$ export | grep OS_
declare -x OS_AUTH_TYPE="password"
declare -x OS_AUTH_URL="http://192.168.20.33:5000/v3"
declare -x OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION="3"
declare -x OS_PASSWORD="XXXXXX"
declare -x OS_PROJECT_NAME="project-name"
declare -x OS_TENANT_NAME="tenant-name"
declare -x OS_USERNAME="from"
declare -x OS_USER_DOMAIN_ID="default"

from@ge ~
$ echo "endpoint list" | openstack
You are not authorized to perform the requested action: identity:list_endpoints. (HTTP 403) (Request-ID: req-aec8b22e-d3ad-4116-b7bb-52545f641667)
```

I've tried to set OS_REGION_NAME to RegionOne, but I get the same result

Any tip ?

Answer (score 0):

- `load-balancer service not found`

It seems that the load balance service not work, have you deployment [`Octavia`](https://docs.openstack.org/project-deploy-guide/charm-deployment-guide/latest/app-octavia.html) service successful?

- `identity:list_endpoints. (HTTP 403)`

According to the official [document](https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/identity/v3/?expanded=list-projects-detail), it's `Forbidden` about the authorization.

> The identity was successfully authenticated but it is not authorized to perform the requested action.

Maybe there is a [miss-configuration](https://bugs.launchpad.net/charms/+source/keystone/+bug/1649106) of the admin's roles in keystone, you should [check it in database](https://bugs.launchpad.net/charms/+source/keystone/+bug/1649106/comments/8) first.

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks for your answers.

I finally managed to play with load balancers using neutron cli:

```
$ neutron
neutron CLI is deprecated and will be removed in the future. Use openstack CLI instead.
(neutron) lbaas-loadbalancer-list
+--------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------+---------------------+----------+
| id                                   | name                   | vip_address    | provisioning_status | provider |
+--------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------+---------------------+----------+
| 00f3453d-8738-4eb6-b362-aefc8dfaeea6 | lb1 | 192.168.36.93  | ACTIVE              | haproxy  |
| 090e062d-d6cc-4ebe-bcbf-165d5c21051d | lb2 | 192.168.36.169 | ACTIVE              | haproxy  |
| 0c244567-8f49-4be0-9055-17fa903d4619 | lb3 | 192.168.36.43  | ACTIVE              | haproxy  |
```